# Detect when the iframe inside another iframe is loaded from third(parent) iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, settimeout

Brainf... with iframes.

So, current page structure:

```
page -> main_iframe -> iframe1 -> iframe2
```

The scripts are executed in "main_iframe".
This "main_iframe" has "iframe1" and "iframe1" has "iframe2" inside:

I want to change width=100% of iframe2 which is inside iframe1, which is inside main_iframe

SO i am executing following js at "main_iframe" and it works:

```
document.querySelector('#iframe1').onload = function() {

setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('#iframe1').contentDocument.querySelectorAll("iframe")[0].style.width = '100%';
 }, 3000); 

}
```

But how to remove timeout timer so it will render as soon as iframe2 has loaded?

I've tried following:

```
document.querySelector('#iframe1').onload = function() {

document.querySelector('#iframe1').contentDocument.querySelectorAll("iframe")[0].onload = function () {
        document.querySelector('#iframe1').contentDocument.querySelectorAll("iframe")[0].style.width = '100%';
  }

};
```

But without luck, nothing is happening after onload fires.

Comment: Firstly, remove the spaces from the selector -> `querySelectorAll("   iframe")`  After that, remove the 2nd onload (the one inside the 1st onload) as you don't need to wait for the contents of frame2 to load before setting the width to 100% of frame1.

Comment: @Archer space fixed (mistake was made only here at stackoverflow while posting). So after removing of 2nd onload it must start with simple `document.contentDocument....`  , you mean `document.contentDocument.querySelectorAll("iframe")[0].style.width = '100%';`   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the outer iframe with `this` inside the load event handler, which makes it a bit tidier.  This should do what you need...

```
document.querySelector("#iframe1").addEventListener("load", function() {
    this.contentDocument.querySelector("iframe").style.width = "100%";
});
```

Comment: Thanks Archer, actually it works, but sometimes `style.width` is set, sometimes not. Hmm

Comment: There are too many unknowns here.  Can you make a [mcve] of your issue?

Comment: This is issue related to ads, who are waterfalling (passbacking) through iframes. 

I can't make minimal example because:
when i am trying to emulate issue locally on few html tags (or my own vps), the code you suggested me works well and inner iframe is getting it's `style.width` set to 100%, but when i am trying that on live (giant, full of iframes and other media) website (which is not mine, i can add .js only to first iframe source code) - then problem appears.
Sorry for confusing situation.

Comment: I can share you link to public page (but then you'll need proxy of .LV country  to see the issue) ... i don't think it's worth you to start with that. 
Anyway , the question regarding given iframe situation was answered by you. So thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries - glad it helped :)